# Laravel Nova Panel Form Fields Update issue

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-nova

I am working on nova panel in localhost..
When i perform update my form fields that time i will see this warning...

> "Another user has updated this resource since this page was loaded.
> Please refresh the page and try again."

also i am getting (409 - Conflict) in ajax.

any solution for that?

I will perform cache clear operation

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan view:clear
```